# module 'a' has no attribute func()

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, attributeerror

I have 2 modules:
a:

```
    import another_module
    def func():
```

b:

```
    import a
    x=a.func()
```

This is showing error: module 'a' has no attribute 'func'. What i am doing wrong in importing a.ipynb

Comment: Try `dir(a)` and see what you get.

Comment: Not enough info for an authoritative answer. What you should do is inspect the content of the imported module `a` after importing it. Do this using `print(dir(a))`. It could be that the module you are importing is not the one you think.

Comment: You cannot import an `a.ipynb`, when you do `import a` it will import `a.py` or the package under the directory `a/`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your module is names 'a.py', and it is in the same folder as b, otherwise, in the place where all the other modules are stored.